# MDX to retrieve year and months with lag on month

Tags: mdx

I have a hierarchy Time of [year].[month]

I want to gets rows years and months, going back six periods, but I also want to show the year.

So this I can do, using lag to find a set of months, and then Ascendants.

```
SELECT
NON EMPTY {[Measures].[modality]} ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY {Hierarchize(Generate({[Time.CalYearMonth1].[2016].[1].lag(6):[Time.CalYearMonth1].[2016].[1]},ASCENDANTS([Time.CalYearMonth1].CurrentMember)))}
 ON ROWS
FROM [mt_report]
```

When I do this, I get a row for the year member, which is basically a row I don't want.

In Pentaho, this gives the result:

```
Axis #0:
{}
Axis #1:
{[Measures].[modality]}
Axis #2:
{[Time.CalYearMonth1].[All Time.CalYearMonth1s]}
{[Time.CalYearMonth1].[2015]}
{[Time.CalYearMonth1].[2015].[7]}
{[Time.CalYearMonth1].[2015].[8]}
{[Time.CalYearMonth1].[2015].[9]}
{[Time.CalYearMonth1].[2015].[10]}
{[Time.CalYearMonth1].[2015].[11]}
{[Time.CalYearMonth1].[2015].[12]}
{[Time.CalYearMonth1].[2016]}
{[Time.CalYearMonth1].[2016].[1]}
Row #0: 0.95
Row #1: 1.11
Row #2: 1.08
Row #3: 1.14
Row #4: 1.13
Row #5: 1.16
Row #6: 1.15
Row #7: 1.15
Row #8: 1.11
Row #9: 1.17
```

I don't know how to avoid the summary per year.

Answer (score 0):

`ASCENDANTS` definitions seems to suggest it will return members from all levels above - this will include the All level which it sounds like you'd like to avoid.

You could try `Ancestors` to get just the Years:

```
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    {[Measures].[modality]} ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
    {
      Hierarchize
      (
        {
          [Time.CalYearMonth1].[2016].[1].Lag(6) : [Time.CalYearMonth1].[2016].[1]
         ,Generate
          (
            {
              [Time.CalYearMonth1].[2016].[1].Lag(6) : [Time.CalYearMonth1].[2016].[1]
            }
           ,Ancestors
            (
              [Time.CalYearMonth1].CurrentMember
             ,1 //<<<change this to the distnace year is away from month in the levels of the user hierarchy
            )
          )
        }
      )
    } ON ROWS
FROM [mt_report];
```

Seems to test ok in `AdvWrks`:

```
SELECT 
  {} ON 0
 ,Hierarchize
  (
    {
        [Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[2010]&[4].Lag(6)
      : 
        [Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[2010]&[4]
     ,Generate
      (
        {
            [Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[2010]&[4].Lag(6)
          : 
            [Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[2010]&[4]
        } AS S
       ,Ancestors
        (
          s.CurrentMember
         ,3   //<<< distance in advwrks between month and year levels
        )
      )
    }
  ) ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

Returns:

[image]

Comment: Could I use filter somehow to remove the tuples in the set which have ALL as the child?

Comment: @TimRichardson can you explain a bit more please - I've never encountered anything with ALL is a child. I have tested my answer against the advWrks cube and it works fine - are you able to adapt to your context?

Comment: the rows where there is just a year, no month, which show the measure aggregated for the whole year ... doesn't that mean that for that "row" the member of month is ALL, that is, the child of the Year is ALL? MDX does my head in. Can Except strip them out?

Comment: I actually thought about your solution myself but I find it very cumbersome, I was hoping that MDX didn't have to be so verbose. I will try it in reality.

Comment: @TimRichardson my solution is based on the approach you have taken in your original piece of code. Originally you had {All, year1, year2, mth1..mth6} and now using my code you have  {year1, year2, mth1..mth6} - is this not what you want? Or do you want year1 to be made up of the sum of only the mths in mth1..mth6 that are from that year?